# Why is the while loop returning false positives?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying out Python 3 and been doing a practice with a while loop but the loop doesn't end when the variable is set to another value different from the default Y

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

elements = [];
copy = [];
rot=0;
op='y';
ap='y';

while op is 'y' or 'Y':

    elements = [];
    a = int(input("How many elements? "));
    for i in range(a):
        elements.append(input("Enter element " + str(i+1) + " "));

    while ap is 'y' or 'Y':
        rot = int(input("How many element to rotate? "));
        print(elements);
        copy = elements[-rot:] + elements[:-rot];
        elements = copy;
        print(elements);
        ap = input("Rotate again? ");

    op = input("Create a new rotatrix? ");
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Comment: Does any of this answers include the OR operator?

Comment: Yes, see the first link.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `is` with strings, only `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **or** operator in your test condition is not working as you intend it to. Try this:

```
elements = []
copy = []
rot=0
op='y'
ap='y'

while op == 'y' or op == 'Y':

    elements = []
    a = input("How many elements? ")
    for i in range(a):
        elements.append(input("Enter element " + str(i+1) + " "))

    while ap == 'y' or ap == 'Y':
        rot = input("How many element to rotate? ")
        print(elements)
        copy = elements[-rot:] + elements[:-rot]
        elements = copy
        print(elements)
        ap = raw_input("Rotate again? ")

    op = raw_input("Create a new rotatrix? ")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @juanpa.arrivillaga you are correct.

Comment: could you add a little explanation? like, "The or operator doesn't take multiple variables..."

Comment: I took the liberty of removing semi-colons from the end of your statements. While syntactically valid, they are discouraged, unless required (i.e. two seperate statements on the same line, e.g. `my_list.append(x); my_list.append(y)`

Comment: Thanks for that, I just used the question's code as a template.

Comment: @userDepth the problem is, something like `op is 'y' or 'Y'` evaluates to `op is ('y' or 'Y')` and `'y' or 'Y'` evaluates to `'Y'`. This is explained in great detail in the duplicates